How to use IP camera with video source object in Matlab
I am trying to use a camera calibration script from the following github repository. I am struggling to adapt this script to use IP cameras. I have no problem running multiple cameras with
cams{i} = ipcam(camURLs{i});

Where I am stuck is how to connect these ipcams to video input so I can run the rest of the script.
for kk = 1:numcams
    if hires ==1
    vid{kk} = videoinput('pointgrey', kk); %, 'F7_YUV422_1328x1048_Mode0');
    else
       vid{kk} = videoinput('pointgrey', kk); %, 'F7_YUV422_656x524_Mode4');
    end
    
    src = getselectedsource(vid{kk});
    vid{kk}.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
    vid{kk}.TriggerRepeat = 1000;
    
    triggerconfig(vid{kk}, 'manual')
    
    vid{kk}.ReturnedColorspace = 'rgb';
    set(vid{kk}, 'LoggingMode', 'Disk&Memory');
    logfile_names{kk} = strcat(parentpath,filesep,logfile_tag,num2str(kk),'.avi');
    logfile{kk} = VideoWriter(logfile_names{kk});
    
    vid{kk}.DiskLogger = logfile{kk};
    start(vid{kk})
end

My feeble attempt at a solution

>> vidobj = videoinput("winvideo",1);
>> cam1 = ipcam('http://172.16.135.98:8080/video')

cam1 = 

  ipcam with properties:

         URL: 'http://172.16.135.98:8080/video'
    Username: ''
    Password: ''
     Timeout: 10

>> vidobj.SelectedSourceName = 'cam1'
Error using indexing (line 33)
There is no enumerated value named 'cam1' for the 'SelectedSourceName' property
Type 'imaqhelp' for information.
 

